# How can I send message error and error status to Sftp client (sshd-core, Mina server)

Tags: ssh, sftp, apache-mina

I'm using sshd-core to create a Sftp server. However, I would like to customize failure message when authenticate like authentication fail, Access Denied,..

I tried to write my message to IoSession (((AbstractIoSession)session.getIoSession()).write("Message error")) but it's not work.

Is it possible to send the customize message via ServerSession of sshd-core, Mina server.

Comment: That's way too vague question. 1) SSH (authentication) and SFTP (file access) layers are completely separate. So an answer to either of these would be completely different and hence you should even ask them separately. 2) For SFTP part, it depends on your "file system" implementation, which you didn't tell us anything about.

Comment: So sorry for my missing.
The server i'm using is SshServer (sshd-core  0.14.0) and Mina apache.
I'm using CustomizePasswordAuthenticator which implements from PasswordAuthenticator. At the method authenticate(...) i would like to throw the detail message error below when any error occur.

I tried (((AbstractIoSession)session.getIoSession()).write("Message error")) but it's not work